# What is the order of a group given three generators, $a^2=b^3=c^4=1$ and $cb=ac$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-presentation, finitely-generated

A group $G=\langle a,b,c\mid a^2=b^3=c^4=1, cbc^{-1} = a\rangle $ what is the order of the group $G$ give all such possible values.

My attempt:
Since $cbc^{-1} =a \Rightarrow cb = ac\;\;(*)$, but then if multiply $(*)$ with $a$ from the left we get
$$acb = c$$
And if we multiply $(*)$ with $b^2$ from the right we get
$$c = acb^2$$
But then we get
$acb^2 = acb \Rightarrow b^2 = b$ so $b=1$ then $a=1$. So the only options either $G = \langle c \rangle $ or $G=1$ the trivial group so either $|G|=4$ or $|G|=1$. Is that correct?

This is a question from a Preliminary algebra exam in a university.

Comment: The group given by any particular presentation is uniquely defined.

Comment: You can check what the order is using GAP.

Comment: @Shaun What is GAP?

Comment: See here: https://www.gap-system.org/

Comment: @Shaun "The group given by any particular presentation is uniquely defined" the question said there are several possible values for the order of $G$ find all suck possible values. I was confused because I thought when we are given the generators a generator cannot be the identity. Do you think there is a mistake in the question? Thanks

Comment: There are no restrictions on the individual elements of a generating set for a group. So, for example, if $S \subset G$ is a generating aet and $e \in G$ is the identity then $S \cup \{e\}$ is also a generating set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a Tietze transformation, the group $G$ given by the presentation in question is isomorphic to

$$\langle b,c\mid (cbc^{-1})^2=b^3=c^4=1\rangle.$$

But now $1=(cbc^{-1})^2=cb^2c^{-1}$, so that $1=c^{-1}c=c^{-1}(cb^2c^{-1})c=b^2$. Then $b=b(b^2)=b^3=1.$ This, again by Tietze transformation, means

$$G\cong\langle c\mid c^4\rangle.$$

The RHS is a presentation of $\Bbb Z_4$. Hence $|G|=4$.

Comment: Thanks your comments and answer are informative not just answering the question but gives more topics to look into.

Comment: You're welcome, @IrbidMath. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

Since $a$ and $b$ are conjugate,  they have the same order.   But the order of $a$ divides $2$, that of $b$ divides $3.$  Thus $a=b=e$.

Thus a presentation for $G$ is$\langle c\mid c^4\rangle, $ and we have $G\cong  \Bbb Z_4.$

Comment: The order of $c$ not only divides $4$, it is equal to $4$.

Comment: So $\mathbb Z_2$ and the trivial group are *not* possibilities.

Comment: @LeeMosher you're right.

Comment: Nitpicking: $G$ does not *equal* a presentation.

Comment: @Shaun thanks for the touch-up